# Pipe with multiple child process

Tags: linux, c

I want to create N processes from one parent and this child processes have to read that parent write, but what i have only the first process reads correctly:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){


pid_t pid;

int fd[2];
char buff[50];

char str[] = "Hello";

if(pipe(fd) == -1){
    fprintf(stderr, "pipe Failed");
    return 1;
}

for(int num_process = 0; num_process < 3; num_process++){
    pid = fork();
    if(pid < 0){
        perror("Error");
        exit(1);
    }

    if(pid == 0){ //child code
        printf("Child %i (pid= %i)\n", num_process, getpid());


    close(fd[1]);
    read(fd[0], buff, sizeof(buff)); //read from pipe
    printf("Read child = %s\n", buff);
    close(fd[0]);
    exit(0);
    }

    else{//parent
        printf("Im parent %i\n",getpid());
        close(fd[0]);
        write(fd[1], str,strlen(str)+1);
        printf("Parent send %s\n", str);
        close(fd[1]);
        for(int num_process = 0; num_process < 3; num_process++){
        wait(NULL);
        }
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

output:

```
Im parent 5863
Parent send Hello
Child 0 (pid= 5864)
Read child = Hello
Im parent 5863
Parent send Hello
Child 1 (pid= 5865)
Read child = 
Im parent 5863
Parent send Hello
Child 2 (pid= 5866)
Read child =
```

Comment: OT: regarding: `int main(int argc, char *argv[]){`  when the parameters to `main()` are not being used, then use the signature: `int main( void )`

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding: 1)  consistently indent the code.  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.

Comment: OT: the posted code contains some 'magic' number.  I.E. 3.  'magic' numbers make the code more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest using an `enum` statement or a `#define` statement to give that 'magic' number a meaningful name, then use that meanindful name throughout the code.

Comment: regarding: `if(pid < 0){
        perror("Error");
        exit(1);`  This will have the parent exiting while one or more children processes are still running.  (a handy  to create zombie processes.)  Suggest inserting a `wait()` or `waitpid()` for each child process before calling `exit()`

Comment: Regarding: `for(int num_process = 0; num_process < 3; num_process++)
   {
    wait(NULL);
   }`  This loop is inside the loop that is creating the child processes.  It should be after all the children are created

Comment: the posted code is missing the following header include statement for the function: `wait()`  `#include <sys/wait.h>`

Comment: there is no need to have the header file: `stdio.h` included twice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> read(fd[0], buff, sizeof(buff)); //read from pipe
> printf("Read child = %s\n", buff);
> ```

If you did check the return value of `read` (as you always should) you would've seen that the 2nd and 3rd time it returns -1 and sets `errno` to `EBADF`. That's because you've already closed the read end of the pipe in the first iteration of the loop, in the "parent" part, here:

> ```
>    printf("Im parent %i\n",getpid());
>    close(fd[0]);
> ```

The same thing with the `write` following it:

> ```
>    write(fd[1], str,strlen(str)+1);
>    printf("Parent send %s\n", str);
>    close(fd[1]);
> ```

`fd[1]` will be closed in the 1st iteration of the loop, and the `write` will fail with `EBADF` the 2nd and 3rd time.

Comment: So, what's the purpose of close pipes?

Comment: You should only do the `close(fd[1])` *in the child*.

Answer (score 2):

the following proposed code:

1. handles each child separately
2. performs the desired functionality
3. incorporates the comments to the OPs question
4. caveat: the closing of the pipe ends is somewhat careless in the proposed code

and now the proposed code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

#define MAX_CHILDREN 3

int main( void )
{
    pid_t pid;

    int fd[2];


    char str[] = "Hello";

    for(int num_process = 0; num_process < MAX_CHILDREN; num_process++)
    {
        if(pipe(fd) == -1)
        {
            perror( "pipe Failed" );
            continue;
        }

        pid = fork();

        if(pid < 0)
        {
            perror("fork failed");
            exit(1);
        }

        if(pid == 0)
        { //child code
            char buff[50];
            printf("Child %i (pid= %i)\n", num_process, getpid());
            close(fd[1]);

            if ( read( fd[0], buff, sizeof(buff)) <= 0) //read from pipe
            {
                perror( "read failed" );
                exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
            }

            printf("Read child = %s\n", buff);
            exit(0);
        }

        else{//parent
            printf("Im parent %i\n",getpid());
            close(fd[0]);
            write(fd[1], str,strlen(str)+1);
            printf("Parent send %s\n", str);
            wait(NULL);
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

A typical run of the code results in:

```
Im parent 26451
Parent send Hello
Child 0 (pid= 26452)
Read child = Hello
Im parent 26451
Parent send Hello
Child 1 (pid= 26453)
Read child = Hello
Im parent 26451
Parent send Hello
Child 2 (pid= 26454)
Read child = Hello
```

Answer (score 0):

Pipes are end to end, what you are trying to do is a chat.